# Spring Boot application taking long time to acquire a db connection for first time response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

Hi all i am  new to Spring boot.
When i am trying to get the data for the first time  API is taking long time to respond. Once the data is returned then next calls are giving response instantly. But if the API is not called for next 6 minutes then next call is again taking longer time. Sorry for poor grammar.

spring boot version: **2.0.3 RELEASE with jpa**

database: **Mysql**

Configuration

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://*************
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: ********
    password: ********
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 30000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      maxLifetime: 1800000
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: This smells like caching. The first query forces the app to load all it needs to process the query, the second query is running open doors. Are you just interested in why it happens, or is the first query **so** slow that it's a problem?

Comment: Define long time please?

Comment: simple get api with data 985B  is taking  20- 35sec first time. where next call to the same api  responds in 64ms

Comment: Can you confirm what is taking 35 sec? Is it the query running in the database or is it the Spring code?

Comment: Spring code is just a findall call.

Comment: looks like it is taking time to acquire the connection with database.Do i need to add anything in configuration?

Comment: @Surendhra:If it is taking too much time to acquire connection from database, try implementing connection pooling.

Comment: @Surendhra jdbc url contains ip address, domain name or localhost?

Comment: @Flame239  it contains ip address

Comment: A findAll call? About how many records are we talking here and how is the datamodel? Even if the records are small, as you point out it is a 985 Byte response, there might be an object hierarchy involved that makes the queries complex.

Comment: @cheffe  there is no such complex hierarchy in my model.  If  the query is  complex it should reflect in  next calls too ryt.

Comment: @mumpitz i am curious to know why  such a simple query is taking half minute to  fetch result for the first time. And  also i  didn't mention anything about caching in my configuration.